# Ffmpeg options for Android?

Tags: ffmpeg

What ffmpeg options should I use to make video playable on Android Phone (specifically, LG Optimus)? I tried various bitrate and codecs and all combinations I came up with doesn't work (tried theora, mpeg4, h264).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reviews I've read seem to indicate that the Optimus will happily play standard-definition Xvid and DivX video files in AVI format so try using the "-vcodec mpeg4" setting.

http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC20

Answer (score 2):

No luck with avi mpg4/mp3 codec? Plays like a charm on my HTC Desire w/ Froyo 2.2
You could also try another encoder, "SUPER" [1] for example. IMHO "Rockplayer" [2] is the best player for the android platform at the moment.

Hope that helps.

[1] http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html

[2] http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/index_en.html

Comment: mpeg4 + libmp3lame was the first thing I tried (can't remember actual bitrate though).

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use any old AVI or MPEG files with the [VPlayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vplayer-%28free-trial%29/me.abitno.vplayer) app without having to convert them.  Another alternative is [Rockplayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/rockplayer-lite/com.redirectin.rockplayer.android.unified.lite).  VLC for Android is supposed to be coming in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you attempt the free [MoboPlayer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&feature=search_result) from the Android market.

It has highly optimised code for ARMV7, ARMV6 VFP, and ARMV6 -- as soon as it downloads it might recommend a different version from the Market version and will automatically start a download of the correct version.

In my personal experience video playback was exceptional on supposedly weaker phones -- although I don't expect it to handle HD content well.

Answer (score 0):

These settings work very well on my ZTE Blade.  As they have similar hardware (CPU & Memory wise) they should work OK for the Optimus One.

Video codec: x264
Frame size: 512*288 (you may want to finesse that slightly for the Optimus screen size - 320*480?)
Bitrate: 768

Audio codec: aac
Bitrate: 128

I suspect that the frame size, codecs (audio and video) and bitrates should be fine regardless of which container (AVI/DIVX/MP4/MKV) that you pick to play it through.